# select subset for regression

Tags: python, regression, subset

I have the following codes that I want to use. The column 0 is year (1950-2020) then the rest of the columns are months. I only want to use the data from 1979-2020 in my linear regression model.

Can you help me? I am quit[image]e a beginner in using python. Below is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
clf = LinearRegression()

data1 = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Users\User-PC\sample.csv') 
x1 = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Year','Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'])
#data2 = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Users\User-PC\sample2.csv', parse_dates=[0], index_col=0) 
#x2 = pd.DataFrame(data2,columns=['Year','Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'])

plt.plot(x1['Year'], x1['Jan'], color='green')
plt.title('Model 1')
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('index')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter your dataframe by year before applying linear regression:

```
new_df = df[df['Year'].between(1979, 2000, inclusive="both")]
```